# Equivalent to template tag in Vue's render function

Tags: vue.js

In Vue's template syntax you can use a template tag to group DOM elements together without the render actually creating a DOM element. e.g.:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ content }}</p>
</template>
```

How can the same thing be achieved with the render function? The following does not work:

```
render(h) {
  return h('template', [
    h('h1', this.title),
    h('p', this.content)
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Components with [render functions](https://alligator.io/vuejs/introduction-render-functions/) do not have a template tag or property. You can do something like this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {
    input: '# hello'
  },
 render(h) {
    return h('div', 
    [
      h('p', 'Example Text')
    ])
  },

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/marked@0.3.6"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.16.0"></script>

<div id="editor"></div>
```

Comment: If you look at your example you are returning a 'div' with a 'p' tag nested in it. I want to return multiple elements without a wrapper... Like the built in <template> tag used in v-for loops.

Comment: @McShaman `render functions` do not have `template` tag or property